# Get first N characters from string without cutting the whole words

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, substring, words

I want to know if there an easy way to get only N symbols from string without cutting the whole words.

For example, I have products and products descriptions information. The description length is from 70 to 500 symbols, but I want to display only the first 70 symbols like this:

> Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in
>   history, as well as the best-known brand in the world.
>
> On May 8, 2011, Coca-Cola celebrated its 125thanniversary. Created in
>   1886 in Atlanta, Georgia, by Dr. John S. Pemberton, Coca-Cola was
>   first offered as a fountain beverage at Jacob's Pharmacy by mixing
>   Coca-Cola syrup with carbonated water.

So, ordinary sub string method will give me:

```
Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in histor
```

and I need a method to get only this:

```
Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in ...
```

Comment: Symbols? Do you mean "characters"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = "Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in history, as well as the best-known brand in the world."
s = s.split(" ").each_with_object("") {|x,ob| break ob unless (ob.length + " ".length + x.length <= 70);ob << (" " + x)}.strip
#=> "Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in"
```

Answer (score 8):

Just use truncate with separator option:

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", length: 17)
# => "Once upon a ti..."
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away", length: 17, separator: ' ')
# => "Once upon a..."
```

Get more info at: [truncate helper in rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate)

Comment: 'Once upon a time in a world far far away'.truncate(17, separator: ' ')

Answer (score 5):

This method uses a regexp which greedily grabs up to 70 characters and subsequently matchs a space or end of string to accomplish your goal

```
def truncate(s, max=70, elided = ' ...')
  s.match( /(.{1,#{max}})(?:\s|\z)/ )[1].tap do |res|
    res << elided unless res.length == s.length
  end    
end

s = "Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in history, as well as the best-known brand in the world."
truncate(s)
=> "Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in ..."
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this solution.  Could you tell me what's going on?

Comment: @JakeSmith We match s string to be potentially truncated against a regexp pattern. The pattern consists of a clause to greedily match 1 to max repetitions of any character `(.{1,#{max}})` as a capture group, followed by a clause to do a non-capturing match of either a whitespace char or end of string `(?:\s|\z)`.  The `[1]` on the match result extracts the first capture.  If that capture is shorter than the whole string, it appends the ellipses.

Comment: Note, this might not work as expected when there is no white space or end of string in the first max characters.  E.g. truncate(s, 3) results in "ola ..." rather than "Col ..." or perhaps just "...". If in this case you'd prefer to get the first n characters, then see inspired solution below.

Answer (score 1):

```
s[0..65].rpartition(" ").first << " ..."
```

In your examle:

```
s = "Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in history, as well as the best-known brand in the world."    
t = s[0..65].rpartition(" ").first << " ..."
=> "Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in ..."
```

Comment: Nice, but if sentence hasn't any space, "..." would be returned

Answer (score 0):

(Inspired by dbenhur's answer but better handles the case where there is no white space or end of string in the first max characters.)

```
def truncate(s, options = { })
  options.reverse_merge!({
     max: 70,
     elided: ' ...'
  });

  s =~ /\A(.{1,#{options[:max]}})(?:\s|\z)/
  if $1.nil? then s[0, options[:max]] + options[:elided]
  elsif $1.length != s.length then $1 + options[:elided]
  else $1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b="Coca-Cola is the most popular and biggest-selling soft drink in history, as well "

def truncate x
a=x.split("").first(70).join

w=a.split("").map!.with_index do |x,y|
    if x!=" "
        x=nil
    else
        x=y
    end
end
w.compact!
index=w.last

x.split("").first(index).join+" ..."
end

truncate b
```